# Stop rotation on Index Trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusgo

I'm creating a Vr-world with unity for the OculusGo.
I'm using the OVR CameraRig and the Oculus utilities.
I have a Model that is rotating by the following script:

```
public class rotation_2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool _shouldRotate = true;

void Update()
   {
    if (_shouldRotate)
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * 8, 0));
   }

void OnMouseDown()
   {
    if (_shouldRotate)
        _shouldRotate = false;
   }
}
```

Right now tho model rotates and stops rotating when the Mousebutton is pressed. It should continue rotating when the Mousebutton is released - but it doesn't. Why?

In the next step i Want to change from the Mouse to the OculusGo-controller.
So it's not the Mousebutton that causes the "rotation-stop" but the OculusGo-controller.

Thank You and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

> Right now tho model rotates and stops rotating when the Mousebutton is
>   pressed. It should continue rotating when the Mousebutton is released
>   - but it doesn't. Why?

You're using the `OnMouseDown` event. That event is always going to fire when the mouse button is pressed, thus setting `_shouldRotate` to false and stopping the movement.
You need to use the `OnMouseUp` event, that will fire when the mouse button is released.

> In the next step i Want to change from the Mouse to the
>   OculusGo-controller. So it's not the Mousebutton that causes the
>   "rotation-stop" but the OculusGo-controller.

For this next step, you need to find the OculusGo Documentation and find the events that are being fired when a button is pressed and released. You will have to find something similar to `OnMouseUp` and; probably, check an argument sent to the function to identify the button that fired the event.

Hope this helps and merry christmas to you too.